# parsing or reading a cpp file using python and adding data by ignoring cpp file comments

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, python-3.x, parsing

I have one cpp file and I am reading that file and trying to add line/lines into that cpp file using python script. I am getting one problem - because it's reading single line comments and multi line comments also so creating problem because if I am writing after/before certain string sometimes it is getting added in comments sections also, which should not happen at all.

Can someone please guide how can I ignore cpp style {NOT REMOVE} while parsing cpp file using python?

For example I am reading a file from back and trying to add `some text` as soon as it finds two `}` (closing braces) it adds `some text`.

For example:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        class C { 

        };
    <Want to add some data here>
    }
}
```

But if I have some commented code:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        class C { 

        };
    <Want to add some data here>
    }
}
```

If I have comments like this:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        class C { 

        };
    <Want to add some data here>
    }
}
// }
/*
int fun() {
}
*/
```

How can I ignore these comments and add `some text` after reading two `}` from back side?

NOTE - You can help me to get some code with different example also.
Please let me know for more info.

Comment: To do this properly, you really need a C++ parser.  You could run your file through [gcc-xml](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) and use an XML module to process it.

Comment: Thanks for the response paddy but I didn't get actually. Can I request you to please me understand with any of the example ? please

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you need to do this with Python, and exactly what you are using it for...  because there are possibly many solutions to your problem that you haven't thought of.

Comment: I want to do this with python because my whole tool is going to be written in python and partially is been already developed. This is one of the point where I got stuck badly. If there is solution pls help

Comment: This is the code I am using for // type of comment      cpat = re.compile("//.*")
        print re.findall(cpat,t)  and for this /* */ style I am using this     comment = re.compile(r'/\*(.*?)\*/', re.DOTALL)
        print re.findall(comment,t)

Comment: If you want your tool to *actually work* regardless of what code you give it, you need a full C++ program transformation system (http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html  see DMS link).  If you insist that your files are *always* shaped to let you do this easily, than a hacky solution might work; not my bet.

Comment: @paddy: how does gcc-xml help?  Yes, it parses, and that is *necessary*.  That gives you an XML document as the parse. But it isn't *sufficient* How is is going to regenerate C++ code from that?

Comment: Consider what happens if you have a multine comment /* ... */ that contains your example text.  You don't want to insert your data in the middle of the comment, so your tool must at least know about comments.  OK, let's make the problem worse.  What if the location of interest is inside a macro expansion?  Regex is often tried for this kind of task, and it always fails.

Comment: I don't know if that tool is sufficient, but I would have expected it's possible to use it to tokenize the file.  You wouldn't reconstruct the source from the XML -- you'd just use it to locate the position where you want to start inserting text.

Comment: I guess just locating is not the idea. Idea is to find and Ignore those comments while parsing - I was able to write some code. That doesn't look 100% correct to me but upto some extent it is. Need your input guys - -

Comment: I am not able paste that code here as it says - it is exceeding the number of lines. Any clue how can I paste that long code ?

Comment: okay posted as answer, can some please review and help me out

Answer (score -1):

```
import re,pdb
cpat = re.compile('}')
f = open('3.txt','w')
brace = 0
newragex = re.compile(r'/\*.*\*/')
#pdb.set_trace()

for line in reversed(open("xvz.cpp").readlines()):
#       if '/*' and '*/' in line.rstrip():
        if re.search(newragex,line):
#               print "Line is - ", line.strip()
                temp = line.split('/*')
#               print "Temp is - ",temp
#               print "Temp[0] is - ",temp[0]
                if temp[0] == None or temp[0] == ' ' or temp[0] == '':
                        print "Inside Single Line comment - and No Extra element is found in this line"
                        f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
                        continue
                else:
                        print "INside Sinle Line comment - but There is extra non comment portion so checking pattern matching\n"
                        if re.search(cpat,line):
                                print "Pattern matched - increasing brace value\n"
                                brace = brace + 1
                                print "Brace Found - Value of Brace now - ", brace
                                f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
#                               if brace == 2:
#                                       print "Two braces found"
 #                                      f.write('Testing add\n')
                                print line.rstrip()
#                print "Single Line commment Found"
                continue
        if '*/' in line.rstrip():
                count = count + 1
                f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
                continue
        if '/*' in line.rstrip():
                count = count - 1
                f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
                continue
        if '//' in line.rstrip():
                temp = line.split('//')
                if temp[0] == None or temp[0] == ' ':
                        f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
                        continue
                else:
                        if re.search(cpat,line):
                                print "Brace Value Before matching - ",brace
                                brace = brace + 1
                                print "Brace Found - Value of Brace now - ", brace
                                f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
                                if brace == 2:
                                        print "Two braces found"
                                        f.write('Testing add\n')
#                               print line.rstrip()
                continue
        if count == 0:
if re.search(cpat,line):
                        brace = brace + 1
                        print "Brace Found - Value of Brace now - ", brace
                        f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
                        print "Brace Value now -", brace
                        if brace == 2:
                                print "Two braces found"
                                f.write('Testing add\n')


#       if brace == 2:
#               print "Two braces found"
#               f.write('Testing add\n')

        else:
                pass

        f.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
```

Comment: regex won't work reliably for this, but you seem to be not listening.  In addition you are processing by lines; how can you handle a multline /* ... **/* construct?  What about /* xx /* yy **/*?  What if /* xx **/*  } /* yy **/*? What if you have a preprocessor directive sequence #if cond newline x } newline #else y } newline #endif?  You need a parser do to this right.

Comment: I totally agree regex won't work reliably but above code covering few of the areas and the same way I can think and add more scenarios like you mentioned  /* xx */ } /* y */? and others ?  What's you call on that, And Regarding the parser I know there is no such library in python which can help me in parsing so how to get that parser ? Do I have to write something like my own compiler ? Just curious to know please help.

Comment: You don't want to write your own compiler for C++; that will take 10 years (from experience) if you have great tools.  Don't know why you insist on using Python, but if you insist, there's Clang with its Python interface library (don't know the name).   There's our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit with its C++ front end; with DMS you can write a transform that will accomplish your effect and handle all the cases (and lots more that I described).